# Node.js solrProxy access denied

Tags: javascript, node.js, solr

I have to use proxy (node.js) to secure solr. I have followed [this guide](https://github.com/dergachev/solr-security-proxy) and perform following steps.

```
npm install solr-security-proxy
```

and then run it

```
`npm bin`/solr-security-proxy --port 9090 --backendHost 127.0.0.1 --backendPort 8983
```

and started solr like

```
java -jar start.jar
```

When I try to query solr via proxy like

```
http://localhost:9090/solr/collection1/select?q=online&wt=json&indent=true
```

It gives follwoing error

```
solrProxy: access denied
```

Same query via solr runs successfully. Where is the problem in my installation of node.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually Node.js allow only read option from solr by supposing format of query prefix like `http://ip-of-system/solr/select/`. In my case I was also giving solr collection name. By removing collection name, above problem was removed. query new format will be like

```
http://localhost:9090/solr/select?q=online&wt=json&indent=true
```